# After hard drive upgrade, battery not charging?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, battery

I just installed a new hard drive into my Macbook Pro 1,1. I had a little difficulty when I initially installed it because the monitor was not turning back on. After re-opening the MacBook Pro (with some difficulty) I closed it up again and it mysteriously worked.

Everything was going swimmingly, but the only problem now is that the battery is not charging. The adapter shows no light on the bit that connects to the computer. It did like 5 minutes ago, then I picked up the computer and it wasn't charging anymore. I tried setting it back down, wiggling the charger, pressing the bottom case areas around the battery. I'm at a loss.

I'm also wondering if I should just invest in a new (or in my case, newer used) MacBook Pro because this one seemed pretty rickety inside. There was no stabilizer bar holding the hard drive in place and some of the tabs holding the keyboard frame down have broken off. I don't really have the money, but this is the way I *make* money.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your hard drive appropriately, you would have never touched your logic board, so I would be surprised if it is broke. How did you replace your hard drive? Do the LED-indicators on the battery still work?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a Logic Board (Motherboard) error. These are costly to fix and require a lot of skill and an expensive replacement.

It is not unusual for repair quotes to be arround £700/$999

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, you've demonstrated why, as a user, it's best to not carry out a non-user service procedure. This kind of repair should be left to trained and seasoned Macintosh technicians, or to those who really know what they're doing and have access to the proper resources.

So in my opinion, the best advice you'll get at this point is to take it to an Apple Authorised Service Provider. Be honest, tell them what happened and they'll open her up and make sure that everything is in its right place and properly seated. Hopefully, you'll  just get slapped with a labour fee. But if it goes further, and things need replacing, they'll be able to quote you.

Act fast though, afaik those particular machines are soon (or already) going to be "unsupported" by Apple, meaning that getting most major parts directly from Apple will no longer be possible.

Comment: acting fast is a tad late as this post was made in July. But good advice none the less.

Comment: I find this answer slightly arrogant. Replacing a hard drive inside a Mac should not cause problems. Try to reset the SMC (System Management Controller) as I have proposed in my answer to the question before spending a lot of money on Apple authorized repair.

Comment: @mgd I'm sorry you feel this way. But the notion of 'should not cause problems' is a particularly naive assumption in *any* case, especially when considering the model of MBP (1st gen). The point still stands - it's not a user-servicable part, so service should be left to trained professionals who are accountable if something goes wrong. Which is the whole point.

Comment: @macaco Sorry for being a little harsh, but you assume the questioner does not have the necessary skills to replace a hard drive. This assumption might be right, but I don't see how your answer helps. I guess the questioner would find out herself to take the Mac to Apple if all else fails. An answer here should be something that possibly helps the person avoiding paying Apple (or others) for fixing the machine for her.

Comment: An answer here should be something that guides the user to the quickest solution. The OP has been very honest and informed us that they had issues when trying to perform the install. These machines can be a little fiddly and the drive is nowhere near as easily accessible as in newer models. This is why it's best left to an experienced or certified tech. Sometimes, you have to pay. Sometimes, you have to pay more if you weren't willing to pay for proper service in the first instance. Non-user-servicable part.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same problem after installing a second hard drive (where the optical drive normally sits).

My solution was to reset the SMC (System Management Controller) which among other things controls the battery charging circuitry.

The procedure is really simple and is described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) but depends on the model of MacBook Pro you have.